# pow(10, x) crashes on ios 6

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is using DTCoreText included in project as Pod. It crashes on iOS 6 when calling `powf(10, x)` with message "Symbol not found: ___exp10f". It seems like `powf(10, x)` is substituted by compiler or linker with `___exp10f(x)` on iOS 7.0+ and `___exp10f(x)` is missing in iOS 6.

Is there are any way to compile this project in XCode 6 for it properly run on iOS 6? I'm very weak in compiler and linker options.

Answer (score 1):

Is your deployment target and base SDK set up for iOS 6? If not, all sorts of things will be goofy.

There are steps to set it in Xcode here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

[image]

Comment: My base SDK is 8.1 but app must run under 6 too. iOS deployment target is set to 6.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the XCode Tools? powf works fine in my setup (Xcode 6 and iOS 8)

check from terminal if you can access to the relevant man page

```
$ man powf
```

The docs page is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/powf.3.html

update: I did not need to use `#import <math.h>` in my class, maybe on iOS 6 you need it.